# WebClient.DownloadString: Invalid JSON primitive:

Tags: c#, php, json

I am trying to download a JSON string from a PHP file on my webserver with WebClient.

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;

private static JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

public static bool GetProgramInfo (string secret_key)
{
   try
   {
      ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += Methods.ValidateRemoteCertificate;
      ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

      using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
      {
         client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
         client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, useragent);
         string jsonData = client.DownloadString(url);
         MessageBox.Show(jsonData);
      }
   }
   catch (Exception e) { MessageBox.Show(e.ToString()); } 
}
```

I tried removing all code that has to do with JSON, including the using statements.
The program goes into break mode exactly at `string jsonData = client.DownloadString(url);` and I get the error `System.ArgumentException: 'Invalid JSON primitive: .'`. The error still shows when I try to use `.ToString()`.

The PHP script returns the data from a SQL table as shown here:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, value FROM `kl_general`");
$stmt->execute();

while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
   if (intval($row['id'] == 5))
      $version = $row['value'];
   else if (intval($row['id']) == 6)
      $hash = $row['value'];
}

$jsonFormat = json_encode(array('version' => $version, 'hash' => $hash));
die($jsonFormat);
```

When I directly access the file on my server I get the indented results: `{"version":"3.0.0","hash":"a28fa7bab9878e42121efccb4e9277a8"}`

**Update**

I attempted using `HttpClient` instead of `WebClient` using the code below with the same error being produced:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;

var handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password) }
using (var client = HttpClient(handler))
{
   var result = client.GetStringAsync(url);
   MessageBox.Show(result.Result);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using HttpClient instead?  Not sure that will fix the error you are experiencing, but Microsoft recommends it going forward with new development.  `We don't recommend that you use the WebClient class for new development. Instead, use the System.Net.Http.HttpClient class.`

Comment: @hijinxbassist I tried using the HttpClient class instead and it still gave me the same error.

`using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
{
   var result = client.GetStringAsync(url);
   MessageBox.Show(result.Result);
}`

Comment: Can you test a different string value for the return from your php (preferably not json).  It almost seems like the web client (or your server) is trying to validate the response.